# Unlogical point size in map in R

Tags: r, maps

I am making simple maps in R, using different colours and sizes for the points on the map. The data comes from a an excel table that I made:

```
PictureStoneID  Place_Name           Reference_Name  X           Y          style    count
473             Briongos de Cervera  Burgos X52     -3,502222    41,915     Burs        1
325             Olleros de Pisuerga  Palencia X1    -4,286667    42,743611  grid        1
566             Villadecanes         León X47       -6,759167    42,579722  Tingstäde   2
566             Villadecanes         León X47       -6,759167    42,579722  Vallstena   2
401             Coruña del Conde     Burgos X40     -3,39675     41,763278  Tingstäde   1
471             Valdelateja          Burgos X51     -3,622222    42,995556  Tingstäde   1
402             Amaya                Burgos X120    -4,1629      42,64225   Tingstäde   2
397             Amaya                Burgos X121    -4,1629      42,64225   Tingstäde   2
846             Olleros de Pisuerga  Palencia X13  -4,286667    42,743611   Tingstäde   1
1062            Vivar del Cid        Burgos X124   -3,679444    42,421944   Tingstäde   1
```

The column "style" will be used for different colors and the column "count" will show the point size (it count the frequency of items with the same coordinates).
This is the code that I am using to create the map:

```
rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-10, 5), ylim = c(36, 44), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = rpat2,
             aes(x = x, y = y, colour = style, size = count),
             na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL)
```

[image: This is the result that I am getting.]

As you can see, it shows point sizes like 1.25 and 1.75, which makes no sense. There can only be one or two items with the same coordinates based on this data. What do I need to do to show only point sizes for one and two and get rid of all those with digits after the comma?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set breaks in the size scale.

Comment: `+ scale_size_continuous(breaks = 1:2)` should do it

Comment: You could also try `+scale_size_area(breaks = 1:2)` if you want the points to better reflect the relative magnitudes of the counts.

Comment: Thank you, Both Allan's and Andrew's suggestions work fine. 
I like Andrew's version a bit better in which the point size reflects the relative magnitude of the counts, although the point sizes are quite big. Can I reduce the size manually?

Comment: And what would I need to do if I had other counts for a coordinate, like 3 or even 10?

Comment: You can use `breaks = 1:10` (or a bigger number - it will only use what it needs). To limit the size, add an option `range = c(1, 4)` (pick two numbers that work for you!).

Comment: Where in the code would I put range = c(1, 4)? I tried it in this line:
aes(x = x, y = y, colour = comparison, size = count, range = c(1, 4))
But I get the following error:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: rangeError in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): range